# How to overcome an error from missing data in a DataReader Iterrows loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, pandas-datareader

I'm attempting to extract historic stock prices for 500 stocks from Yahoo Finance using pandas DataReader. I've got the code to work in limited cases but I've been problem with some stock tickers that for some reason aren't supported by Yahoo finance and therefore I can extract their data.

The "No Data" stops my code working. I'd like to create code that would have a robust universal application so it would work when data is available, and then just fill a "NaN" if there isn't. I'm sure this is straight forward but just can't get my head around it.

I tried fixing the problem with `if` and `else` conditions but whatever I tried wasn't working and just couldn't figure it out.

```
style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2019,5,26)

data = pd.DataFrame([])

for index, row in tickers.iterrows():

    #if web.DataReader(row['ticker'] , 'yahoo').any():
    df = web.DataReader(row['ticker'] , 'yahoo', start, end)
    df['ticker'] = str(row['ticker'])
    data = data.append(df)

    #else:
      #  df = 'Nan'
        #df['ticker'] = str(row['ticker'])

print(data.head())
```

I'd like to create DataFrame of all the historic stock prices for a given list of tickers that I've imported tickers symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna), or perhaps [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna).

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it's that straight forward as I'm not working with an existing data file, I'm extracting data directly from Yahoo Finance with Pandas DataReader which is working for most ticker symbols but not all. Some tickers are missing in Yahoo Finance which is then causing a "RemoteDataError" for those missing tickers. I'm trying to loop over/ignore any missing ticker symbols when pulling data from Yahoo. The error message I'm getting is (first missing ticker is "AET" as in error below): 
```RemoteDataError: No data fetched for symbol AET using YahooDailyReader```